# C# Resizing array of int then display value

Tags: c#, arrays

Now I am using a ReadMemory library which provides how to read process memory.
In this stage I am understand how to use it. But my problem is like this:

```
public  int[] a = { 0x100, 0x4, 0x0, 0xCC, 0x400 };
public  int[] b = { 0x100, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0xCC, 0x400 };
public  int[] c = { 0x100, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xCC, 0x400 };
public  int[] d = { 0x100, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xCC, 0x400 };
```

As you can see the value `0x0` is increasing in the middle of `int[]`. So now I have create something like this:

```
public  int[] b;
public  int[] a = { 0x100, 0x4, 0x0, 0xCC, 0x400 };

 for (int i = 5; i <= 100; i += 1)
        {
            b = (int[])ResizeArray(a, i);

            b[i - 1] = 0x400;
            b[i - 2] = 0xCC;
            b[i - 3] = 0x0;

            a = b;
            int read1;
            read1 = ReadMemoryPointerInt(0x04000000, a);
            if (read1 == 1000000)
            {
                Listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { i.ToString() }));
            }

        }
```

**The code above is working but not perfectly**. I've found that the count was duplicate but have no idea which line of code is wrong. **And sometimes the print out `i` is more than the real match value** which is not true.

The resizing code :

```
public static System.Array ResizeArray(System.Array oldArray, int newSize)
    {
        int oldSize = oldArray.Length;
        System.Type elementType = oldArray.GetType().GetElementType();
        System.Array newArray = System.Array.CreateInstance(elementType, newSize);

        int preserveLength = System.Math.Min(oldSize, newSize);

        if (preserveLength > 0)
            System.Array.Copy(oldArray, newArray, preserveLength);

        return newArray;
    }
```

My question is : What am I doing wrong. And how can I fix the duplicate and over that print out.

PS. As I see the first `i` is correct every times. But the rest `i` sometimes correct and also duplicate from the before `i`.

Comment: is it possible to put working example on .netFiddle?

Comment: "the count was duplicate" yet there is nothing that resembles "count" in code shown... (I understand you are not expected to be serious, but really what the point reimplementing [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?)

Comment: @Simonare The project need some external library too. From this link https://github.com/fenix01/cheatengine-library

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because I need the size to equal to i so I make it in the for loop that also increasing i.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Also I have print out the a its correct up to 100 times. But I don't know why the Listview are wrong. I know it wrong because I also use Cheat Engine to scan the value and the number of value are not match with i

Comment: but why dont you use Array.Resize ??

Comment: As I done tested the result of Array.Resize is the same as ResizeArray